# oAuth with PHP (for google api)

Tags: php, oauth

How to use oAuth with PHP ? I can't install oauth class with pecl because I'm using share hosting.

I found

http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/

but there is no example for client. I want to use oauth for Google API.

Comment: There are links to examples all over that page.  If you google "google api oauth" you get a lot more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it and I develop my own client library base on http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/ ([svn sourcecode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/oauth_playground))

Answer (score 4):

Here is your example: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo

You can also read through http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html to find out the specifics on Google.

Comment: that's oauth1 and not oauth2

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of libraries available for PHP. Check out the list on http://oauth.net/code/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a look at: 
http://www.dhruvb.com/blog/content/tutorial-using-oauth-google-plus-api

Also, the code samples are present at: 
https://github.com/dhruvbaldawa/Tutorials/blob/master/google+/google_plus.php

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean this offical library:

[Offical API Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)