# Requesting user email from Google Api returns unauthorized 401 error

Tags: php, http-headers, file-get-contents, oauth-2.0

I try to connect to google API and it returns:
`failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`
I requested for access token and it returned me xxx, after that I connect to Google API by following PHP code:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header' => "Authorization: OAuth $access_token\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n",
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json',false,$context);
```

Where is mistake did I write wrongly headers, or something else?
Update: $access_token is a value which I got in json by requesting it.

Comment: [Complete OAuth example](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#section-1.2), [PHP Google API Oauth Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084087/oauth-with-php-for-google-api)

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need the content type header for a GET request.
- You need to query this URL to get the User Info: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
- Make sure that the `$access_token` value contains an correctly authorized access token, for that you need your user to go through an OAUth 2.0  flow.

All of this is all documented there: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Answer (score 0):

Check how to do it in php, but when logging your client to Google you must set the RequestPermission parameter so you can get info from user's profile

requestPermissions: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'